# Buffer-local hook shadowing default value for subsequently loaded libraries

Tags: hooks, buffer-local

After having a problem with debugging a package I write, I finally tracked down the problem to the following: `auto-revert-mode` is making `kill-buffer-hook` buffer-local (which is fine by me). The  problem is that every library (auto-)loaded afterwards (while the buffer is still active) only "sees" the buffer-local binding, and any `add-hook` only modifies the buffer-local binding.

Here are a few steps to reproduce the problem using only standard emacs libraries:

```lisp
(find-file "foo.el")

kill-buffer-hook                  ; => (uniquify-kill-buffer-function vc-kill-buffer-hook)
(default-value 'kill-buffer-hook) ; => (uniquify-kill-buffer-function vc-kill-buffer-hook)


;; Turn on `auto-revert-mode': `kill-buffer-hook' becomes buffer-local
(auto-revert-mode)

kill-buffer-hook                  ; => (auto-revert-notify-rm-watch uniquify-kill-buffer-function vc-kill-buffer-hook)
(default-value 'kill-buffer-hook) ; => (uniquify-kill-buffer-function vc-kill-buffer-hook)


;; Subsequently load a library which adds a `kill-buffer-hook'
;;   only the local binding is modified; no other buffer will ever see
;;   the hook installed by `tramp'
(require 'tramp)

kill-buffer-hook                  ; => (tramp-delete-temp-file-function auto-revert-notify-rm-watch uniquify-kill-buffer-function vc-kill-buffer-hook)
(default-value 'kill-buffer-hook) ; => (uniquify-kill-buffer-function vc-kill-buffer-hook)


;; The same thing happens (unsurprisingly) for auto-loaded libraries
(browse-url "emacs.stackexchange.com")

kill-buffer-hook                  ; => (browse-url-delete-temp-file tramp-delete-temp-file-function auto-revert-notify-rm-watch uniquify-kill-buffer-function vc-kill-buffer-hook)
(default-value 'kill-buffer-hook) ; => (uniquify-kill-buffer-function vc-kill-buffer-hook)
```

So I guess my question is: is this normal and desired behaviour? Shouldn't all buffers see the hooks installed by subsequently loaded packages?

Although the problem here is specifically caused by `auto-revert-mode` and `kill-buffer-hook`, I'm guessing this situation is fairly more general and could happen for a lot of libraries and hooks...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. `kill-buffer-hook` is not automatically buffer-local.  That it is, it does not automatically become buffer-local whenever its value is set.
2. AFAICT, `auto-revert-mode` does **not** make `kill-buffer-hook` be buffer-local.
3. Something else in your setup no doubt does make it buffer-local in some buffer.
4. `kill-buffer-hook`, although not buffer-local to start with, has the property that it **if** it is ever made buffer local then it will be buffer-local **permanently**.

   You can see this from `C-h v kill-buffer-hook`:

   > This variable's value is **permanent if it is given a local binding**.

   See the Elisp manual, node [Creating Buffer-Local](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Creating-Buffer_002dLocal.html).  There you will see this:

   > A buffer-local variable is “**permanent**” if the variable name (a
   >   symbol) has a `permanent-local` property that is non-`nil`.  Such
   >   variables are unaffected by `kill-all-local-variables`, and their local
   >   bindings are therefore not cleared by changing major modes.  Permanent
   >   locals are **appropriate for data pertaining to where the file came from
   >   or how to save it**, rather than with how to edit the contents.

   This means that when you use a different major mode the last local
   binding is kept, which is exactly the behavior you reported.
5. If you want to change the buffer-local value then you will need to do so explicitly, using, for example `setq`.  You can also change the default value of the variable, using `setq-default`.

Comment: Thanks for looking at it. Regarding point 2., I had already checked this and found a `(make-local-variable 'kill-buffer-hook)` in file `autorevert.el`. After your comment, I double checked using the latest emacs sources, and it appears the problem has been fixed by commit [9e41e0bc](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/commit/?id=9e41e0bc6a6fdb7a01841db62d8de42d67be534a). And from there I learned that this problem was reported as [bug 20601](http://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=20601)

Comment: Ah! Interesting. And good checking. I too should have looked further than just checking the latest Emacs 25 snapshot I have. Your comment greatly improves this Q & A for others.